# Private static member not accessilble from public static member function?

Tags: c++, scope, visibility, static-members

Let's say I have following code:

```
#define STACK_SIZE 5

class Stack {
    private: static int iStackPos;
    private: static void *rgpvStack[STACK_SIZE];

    public: static void Push (
        void *pvElem);
};

int Stack::iStackPos = 0;
void *rgpvStack[STACK_SIZE];

void Stack::Push (void *pvElem) {
    if (Stack::iStackPos < STACK_SIZE) {               // [1]
        Stack::rgpvStack[Stack::iStackPos++] = pvElem; // [2]
    }
}
```

When I compile this (with AVR-GCC, 03/2012) I get following errors:

- At [1]: `Stack::iStackPos` is private
- At [2]: `Stack::iStackPos` is private
- At [2]: `Stack::rgpvStack` is private

I know that these variables are private, because I marked them with `private:`, because they shoulndn't be accessible outside this class. If I'm not mistaken, `Push` is a member of `Stack`, so `iStackPos` and `rgpvStack` should be accessible within `Push`, or not?

---

**EDIT:**

The original code has 450 lines, but I summarized it a little bit. The functions `loop` and `setup` make use of functions declared in lines with `// ...`. These functions doesn't make any use of my problematic functions and `boolean` is declared somewhere in the headers of the Arduino Uno board. Actually I saw my (very stupid) mistakes when I was shortening my code and marked them (see below). Thank you anyway :)

```
#define STACK_SIZE 5

// ...

class Stack;

// ...

class Stack {
    private: static int iStackPos;
    private: static void *rgpvStack[STACK_SIZE];

    public: static boolean Pop (
        void *pvElem);

    public: static boolean Push (
        void *pvElem);
};

// ...

int Stack::iStackPos = 0;
void *Stack::rgpvStack[STACK_SIZE];



boolean Pop (void *pvElem) {   // !!! Must be Stack::Pop !!!
    // TODO
    return false;
}



boolean Push (void *pvElem) {  // !!! Must be Stack::Push !!!
    if (Stack::iStackPos < STACK_SIZE) {
        Stack::rgpvStack[Stack::iStackPos++] = pvElem;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// ...

void loop () {
    // CLI::ProcessSerial();
    // 
    // // Animate LEDs
    // Prog::pAnim->Calculate();
    // 
    // for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    //     Prog::pMgr->Set(n, Prog::pAnim->pColor);
    // }
    // 
    // Prog::pMgr->Sync();
    // 
    // // Delay
    // delay(BOARD_LOOP_DELAY);
}



void setup () {
    Serial.begin(BOARD_SYMBOL_RATE);
    while (!Serial);

    // Prog::Prog::pMgr = new LedMgr(A0, 5);
    // 
    // Prog::pAnim = new Animation(2000);
    // Prog::pAnim->pfnFinished = Prog::AnimFinished;
    // Prog::pAnim->pInColor = new Color(0, 20, 0);
    // Prog::pAnim->pOutColor = new Color(0, 0, 20);
    // 
    // CLI::ShowHelp();
}
```

Comment: Those members should be accessible in that context. Is this the exact code you're trying to compile?

Comment: Why is everything static?

Comment: Compiles for me after adding `Stack::` to have `void* Stack::rgpvStack[STACK_SIZE];` (VC++).

Comment: After resolving the compilation error (which I can't see in the code you've published), you will have an additional linkage error for `Stack::rgpvStack`.

Comment: This code *hurts*. Hungarian prefix, macro to define a constant, `void*`, static members, ouch! Not to mention a DIY stack when there is `std::stack`. Why?

Comment: To Brian: Everything is static, because I don't need to instantiate this class; To Alf: I like Hungarian notation, because I got used to it. The constant, because I learned it this way (like `#define COMPILE_TIME_CONST 5` and `#define MACRO(PARAM) (PARAM)`). I already answered why I use static members and I don't know what a DIY stack is.

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur if you wrote the definition of the function like

```
void Push (void *pvElem) {
    if (Stack::iStackPos < STACK_SIZE) {               // [1]
        Stack::rgpvStack[Stack::iStackPos++] = pvElem; // [2]
    }
}
```

instead of

```
void Stack::Push (void *pvElem) {
    if (Stack::iStackPos < STACK_SIZE) {               // [1]
        Stack::rgpvStack[Stack::iStackPos++] = pvElem; // [2]
    }
}
```

Take into account that instead of

```
void *rgpvStack[STACK_SIZE];
```

there must be

```
void * Stack::rgpvStack[STACK_SIZE];
```